# Complex model and Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-4.5

I am having a problem in accessing my viewmodel and its partial view model data in controller

**My Model**

```
public class SearchRequest : BaseRequest
{
    public SearchOptions SearchBy{ get; set; }
    // and other properties also there
}

[KnownType(typeof(SearchByAirport))]
[KnownType(typeof(SearchByCity))]
[KnownType(typeof(SearchByProductCodes))]
[KnownType(typeof(SearchByGeocode))]
public abstract class SearchOptions
{
}

public class SearchByProductCodes : SearchOptions
{
    public List<string> Codes { get; set; }
}
public class SearchByGeocode : SearchOptions
{
// few more properties
}
```

**My View**

View has model reference for `SearchRequest` and has a drop down for selecting search category (i.e. search by product codes , geo code, city etc. etc.) and on change of drop down i load my partial view

One of my partial view

```
 @model Tavisca.Catapult.External.DataContract.Common.SearchByProductCodes 

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Codes, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Codes)
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(SearchRequest hotelSearchRequest)
{
    return View();
}
```

i am getting `SearchBy` Null here, What is the best approach to arrange my view and get all fields from view to controller.

Answer (score 0):

The model binder will try and match Codes in the form values with your viewmodel, but it is called SearchBy in there, so it will fail.

try doing this

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Codes, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Codes, new {Name="SearchBy" })
    </div>
</div>
```

That will give the model binder the right field name to pull out.

The other way is to get it manually from the form in your controller action like this:

```
Request.Form["Codes"]
```

Personally, I'd opt for option #1.